How to get argument of opt in llvm pass?
I want to get the argument of opt (the output file after '-o') in a pass.
I have tried the following code. But the compiler reports 'bolt/Utils/CommandLineOpts.h' file not found
 #include "bolt/Utils/CommandLineOpts.h"
std::string output = opts::OutputFilename.getValue(); 
I have checked the build command of llvm. I have set -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;clang-tools-extra;libunwind;lldb;lld;compiler-rt;polly;bolt". This includes bolt subproject.
What should I do?

What is your exact compilation command and output?  Ideally, run it with -v to show the header search paths.

I also want to know the answer. If I use opt ... -o outputfile, how could I get the path of outputfile in the pass?
